# Programmatically move WIT from one Collection/Project to another

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to programmatically move a WIT (PBI, Bug, etc.) from one Collection/Project to another?

I have a use case where a bug may be inadvertently opened under the wrong team project, and needs to be "moved" intact (history, attachments, etc.).

I've seen hacks that involve manipulating the underlying SQL tables, but I'd like a cleaner API-based solution.

Comment: from one Collection/Project to another，Did you mean you want to move WIT from one team project to another but under the same team project collection or you want to move to a different team project collection?

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot** move a work item from project to another or one collection to another. But you can copy it to another project in the same collection using the copy option in Web Access (manually). This actually just creates a new work item and copies all the matching field values to the new item.

If you want to do this in code or if you need to do this from one collection to the another collection you will have to create a new work item and copy all the fields you need over to the new instance. If you need the actual move experience you can destroy the old work item **after** the save of the new item is completed.

Note that you will always get a new ID both since ID's have to be unique within a team project collection. If moving items around is an ongoing concern for you consider moving all related teams into a single team project and use Team's to keep them aparte where necessary. You **can** move work items from one team to another **within the same team project**.

Comment: Thanks. What if the WIT has attachments? Are those easily copyable via the API as well?

Comment: Yes that is possible, you can downlaod and upload the attachments using the api. Have a look at: https://github.com/sanderaernouts/tfs-workitem-tools. I created those migrate work items and copy field values from field A to field B, maybe you can use this as a starting point for your script(s). It's completely powershell by the way. If you have to move a lot of items with complex migration path have a look at https://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/. Be warned though, it is complex..

Comment: I'll check that out, thanks. I'm working in C#. Is there a tool/api to serialize a WIT including its attachments? Wondering if I can basically export the WIT and import it back into the other collection.

Comment: This should do it (skip the remove attachment part though), see: https://roadtoalm.com/2014/12/31/insert-an-inline-image-into-a-work-item-with-the-tfs-api/. To retrieve attachments you can simply enumerate over the attachment collection of the retrieved work item(s) and download them, see: http://www.timschaeps.com/team-foundation-service-downloading-attachments-from-work-items-through-the-api/.